# How to generate SSH on Github using Terminal

Tags: github, ssh

I have deleted by SSH key by mistakenly on Github account, Now i don't know how to add that keys or generate new keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google...

[Generating GitHub SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)

> ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@youremail.com"

This will generate new `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` keys in your ~/.ssh/ directory.

To upload this newly created key to GitHub, go to:

1. Account Settings
2. SSH Keys
3. Add SSH Key
4. Paste your key where applicable - `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or Notepad in windows to get the contents.
5. Add Key
6. Connect

Comment: yup. i always forget to move my keys when i go to a new machine, so my github account has like 6 different ssh keys, one for each machine ;D

Comment: Thanks for the reply however i have multiple ssh key on my machine, so  how do i delete all the keys and make new keys.

Comment: `Back them up` if you have them registered with something else and delete them, you are screwed ^.^ Once they are backed up... Just delete the keys in your ~/.ssh/ directory. And then run the steps I provided above.